# An interview question on conditional operator

Tags: c++, c, conditional-operator

I recently encountered with this question: How to reduce this expression: **s>73?61:60;**.

The hint given was that **Instead of using conditional operator we could use a simple comparison which will work fine**.

I am not sure but I think  it is possible with some GCC extension,although I am unable to figure it out myself.

EDIT:The whole expression is this : `s-=s>73?61:60`

Comment: You don't want to work for people that ask these kinds of questions at interviews.

Comment: The correct answer is "go interview somewhere else that asks worthwhile questions"

Comment: Do people actually ask things like that for "job" interviews? Sorry I am a student yet :D

Comment: @AraK, only people who don't understand what job interviews are for.

Comment: @AraK: Yes, some interviewers who are completely amazed by their own intelligence, and they tell themselves that they only want hire people who are smart enough to answer their obscure and useless trivia questions, but in actually they just want to impress the poor interviewee with how smart they are

Comment: It could've been worse, you could've gotten this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464323/new-hire-expectations-am-i-being-unreasonable

Comment: @Jacob, no kidding.  Some people are *ridiculous*.  I mean, yeah, it's important to find out if the candidate can program, but you find that out from much more reasonable questions.

Comment: FYI: Compiling both Carl's answer and the ternary operator in gcc 4.2.1 with -O3 on x86-64, both come out to identical assembly. Without -O3 (hence running as normal), Carl's answer comes out smaller. HOWEVER why would you release a version that isn't -O3, especially if speed is an issue?

Comment: @Paul, that's exactly why it's an awful question.  Making code harder to read with no other gains is a non-starter.

Comment: Now for the real-world component: orders have come down from your boss' boss that the values behind `73`, `60` and `61` have changed to be `102`, `55` and `73`. How long will it take to update your solution?

Comment: Well, I wanted to see (mostly for my own purposes) if it was an optimization gcc couldn't catch. On the flip side, naive compilers will probably not catch it, and therefore, it's good to remember if I am working with a lousy compiler down the road.

Comment: Are they hiring people for COMPILER position instead of Programmer position :O

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just like the other answers:

```
s -= (s > 73) + 60;
```

This expression works because the spec defines the results of the relational operators. Section 6.5.8 paragraph 6:

> Each of the operators **`<`** (less than), **`>`** (greater than), **`<=`** (less than or equal to), and **`>=`** (greater than or equal to) shall yield **`1`** if the specified relation is true and **`0`** if it is false. The result has type **`int`**.

Comment: Thats an elegant solution for a bad question ;)

Comment: This also works in C++, where the result of the comparison is `bool`, and where `+` promotes integer operands, and where `bool` promotes to `0` and `1` for `false` and `true` respectively. (assuming `s` is a plain `int` and not some class).

Comment: Yeah, but is it a *reduction* actually? :D We'd have to look at asm, wouldn't we? ;)

Answer (score 8):

How to reduce this expression: `s-=s>73?61:60;`

How about:

```
typedef int Price;
Price getPriceAfterRebate(const Price priceBeforeRebate)
{
  const Price normalRebate = 60;
  const Price superRebate = 61;

  const Price superRebateThreshold = 73;

  Price returnValue = priceBeforeRebate;
  if (priceBeforeRebate > superRebateThreshold)
  {
    returnValue -= superRebate;
  }
  else
  {
    returnValue -= normalRebate;
  }
  return returnValue;
}
```

Tada!  An ugly piece of unmaintainable code is reduced to a readable and maintainable block of code.

Comment: @Ari, litb: Glad you enjoyed it.

Answer (score 4):

This is such an ugly piece of code that I can't beleive I wrote it, but I think it fulfills the requirement:

My answer to the original question which was `s>5?6:9`:

`9 - (((int)(s > 5)) * 3)`

Rewritten for the updated question:

`61 - (int)(s > 73)`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this?

```
60 + !!(s > 73)
```

The double-bang maps non-zero values to 1 and zero to zero.

Comment: You don't need to do that, the spec guarantees that the relational operators return 1 or 0.  Section 6.5.8 paragraph 6.

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of `(s>5)`?  Could you do some arithmetic with that?

Without the hint, I would say this was a bad "gotcha" interview question that requires a particular a-ha insight that's not correlated with ability.  With the hint, it's... *nice, but dim*.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that `True = 1` and `False = 0`, then doesn't this work:

```
s-= (60 + (s > 73))
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be thought of as s -= (s > 73) + 60 as > is a relational operator and it will return 1 or 0 depending on result of expression s > 73 ,As the return value is int so it will work fine